# Fastest and most compact way to get the smallest number that is divisible by numbers from 1 to n

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, math

I tried my attempt at finding the smallest number that is divisible by numbers from 1 to n, and now I'm looking for advice on ways to further compact/make my solution more efficient. It would be pretty cool if there was an O(1) solution too.

```
def get_smallest_number(n):
    """
    returns the smallest number that is divisible by numbers from 1 to n
    """
    divisors = range(1, n+1)
    check_divisible = lambda x: all([x % y == 0 for y in divisors])
    i = 1
    while True:
        if check_divisible(i):
            return i
        i += 1
```

Comment: `[x % y == 0 for y in divisors]` -- why create the full list in memory? `all` can short-circuit an iterable. An `O(1)` solution is not likely.

Comment: Your problem is called the "least common multiple", and with this search term you'll find lots of input.

Comment: For "most compact", it's probably going to be hard to beat `math.lcm(*range(1, n+1))`. (Requires Python 3.9, due for release October 2020.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mathematically, you are computing the least common multiple of `1, 2, ..., n`. `lcm` is easily derived from `gcd`, and `lcm` is an associative operation. `reduce` is useful for applying an associative operation to an interable. We can combine these ideas (as well as improvements due to Mark Dickinson and Eric Postpischil in the comments) to get a very fast solution:

```
from math import gcd
from functools import reduce

def lcm(a,b):
    return a // gcd(a,b) * b

def get_smallest_number2(n):
    return reduce(lcm,range(1 + n//2,n+1),1)
```

Some quick `%timeit` results in IPython:

```
%timeit get_smallest_number2(15)
2.07 µs ± 26.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

%timeit get_smallest_number(15)
443 ms ± 5.75 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

For `n = 15` it is thus over 200,000 times faster. Your function fails to produce any output long before `n = 100`, but `get_smallest_number2(100)` evaluates to `69720375229712477164533808935312303556800` almost instantly.

Comment: Maybe `range(2,n+1)`?

Comment: @OlvinRoght Conceptually a good suggestion, although `timeit` doesn't show any real difference.

Comment: `range(n//2+1, n+1)` should be enough, since every value smaller than or equal to `n//2` has its double appear later in the sequence.

Comment: `return a//gcd(a, b) * b` may be preferable. There is never a fraction since the GCD divides `a` (and `b`). In languages with unbounded integer arithmetic, it reduces the work. In languages with fixed integer arithmetic, it avoids unnecessary overflow.

Comment: The computation does not need to be performed for 1 to n. ceil((n+1)/2) to n suffices, since any i < (n+1)/2 has a multiple in ceil((n+1)/2) to n. There may be further optimizations available.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Good points. Your first suggestion leads to a small but measurable improvement for something like `n = 100` and the second one, not surprisingly, makes it roughly twice as fast.

Comment: An even better option is to take the product of only the _odd_ numbers up to `n`, then bit shift for the power-of-two part: `lcm(*range(1, n+1, 2)) << n.bit_length()-1`. The first third of those odd numbers can be discarded, too: `lcm(*range(n//3+1|1, n+1, 2)) << n.bit_length()-1` . But this is just tinkering - the right way to make this efficient is to construct from prime powers, as outlined in @rossum's answer.

Answer (score 3):

Start by thinking about the factorial n!.  This is obviously divisible by all numbers less then n, but is not the smallest such number.  For example, you could divide n! by 6, and the smaller result would still be divisible by 2 and by 3, and hence still divisible by 6.

What numbers can we divide out?  Composites, like 6, don't matter as long as all the required primes are present: 2 and 3 in that case.  The primes give you the composites for free.  So, concentrate on the primes.

Start with 2.  Look at the powers of 2: 2, 4, 8, 16, ... Run through the powers of 2 until you find the highest power that is smaller than or equal to n.  That is the only power of 2 you need, all the lower powers are unnecessary.  You don't need to include 4 explicitly if n is 8 or higher because then you will have 8, 16 or whatever as a multiplier.  Repeat for powers of 3: 3, 9, 27, 81, ... and so on through the primes up to sqrt(n).  Beyond that point you only need the remaining primes less than n, since higher powers of those primes will exceed n.

Multiply the selected prime powers together to get the least n.

Use a Sieve of Eratosthenes to generate your initial list of primes up to n.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to implement LCM

```
import time
from datetime import timedelta


start_time = time.monotonic()
 

def lcm(nums):
    res = 1
    for i in nums:
        res = (res * i) // gcd(res, i)
    return res
    
def gcd(a, b):
    while b:
        a, b = b, a%b
    return a
    
print(lcm([8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]))




end_time = time.monotonic()
print(f'Duration: {timedelta(seconds=end_time - start_time)}')
```

Produces

```
360360
Duration: 0:00:00.000061

[Program finished]
```

Answer (score -2):

The idea is to add highest divider every iteration and check from high to low. Something like this:

```
n = int(input("n = "))
result = 0
while True:
    result += n
    for i in range(n, 1, -1):
        if result % i != 0:
            break
    else:
        break
print(result)
```